# Need help to execute sequential api calls in for-loop

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am working with Angular and NodeJs (with Axios) using RxJs, and currently find it very challenging to achieve this task. I will explain my problem based on a scenario.

I have an array of objects like this, with possibly even more than 100 objects:

```
let objArr = [{name: 'john', id: '123', country: 'usa'}, {name: 'doe', id: '456', country: 'china'}....]
```

Then I have another 4-5 validation APIs that can be called for different params e.g. id, name and country based on each object:

```
api_1 = "validate_step_1/:id"
api_2 = "validate_step_2/:id/:name"
api_3 = "validate_step_3/:id/:country"
api_4 = "validate_step_4/:id:/:name/:country"
```

These API calls should strictly happen one after another in a sequential pattern, e.g. api_2 should only be called if api_1 returns true and so on.

**What I want:**

I would like to execute for-loop on the array that should run in parallel, and each object should then sequentially validate itself based on these 4 API calls. Something like sequential API calls based on each item in for-loop in parallel for all 100 objects.

Is this even possible? Also, any solutions to achieve this on the Node side are also welcomed.

**What I tried**

Right now I am using this method, but it's very slow, even sometimes resulting in timeout errors in Axios:

```
  of(...this.objArr).pipe(
    concatMap((obj: any) => this.service.api_1(id)),
    concatMap((obj: any) => this.service.api_2(id, name)),
    concatMap((obj: any) => this.service.api_3(id, country)),
    concatMap((obj: any) => this.service.api_4(id, name, country)),
    catchError( error => this.handleError(error))
  ).subscribe(
    success => {
      console.log("validation succeed", success);
    },
    errorData => {
      console.log("validation failure: ", errorData);
    }
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would adopt this approach.

First of all create a function that build an Observable that runs all the validations in parallel and handle any error we may encounter (more on errors later). Something like this

```
function validate(id, name, country) {
  return concat(
    this.service.api1(id),
    this.service.api2(id, name),
    this.service.api3(id, country),
    this.service.api4(id, name, country)
  ).pipe(
    catchError(err => of(err.message))
  );
}
```

Then I would use the `from` function from the **rxjs** library to turn the array of objects into a stream and then apply the `mergeMap` operator to launch all the validations in parallel, like this

```
from(objArr)
  .pipe(mergeMap((obj) => validate(obj.id, obj.name, obj.country)))
  .subscribe((v) => console.log(v));
```

Why use `mergeMap` over `forkJoin` in this case. The main reason is that with `mergeMap` you can control the level of concurrency you want to have. If you do not specify anything, all the validations run in parallel. But, for instance, if you want to limit the number of parallel validations, you can use the optional `concurrent` parameter of `mergeMap` like this

```
const concurrent = 3 // whatever limit 
from(objArr)
   .pipe(mergeMap((obj) => validate(obj.id, obj.name, obj.country), concurrent))
   .subscribe((v) => console.log(v));
```

If you want to proceed in the validations only if a certain criteria is met, you can simply use the `tap` operator and `throw` an error if the condition is not met. The error will be caught by the `catchError` operator which we have added at the end of the `pipe` in the `validate` function. So, a validation API would look like this

```
api3(id, country) {
  return this.invokeApi3(id, country).pipe(
    tap(() => {
      if (// check the criteria for which you do not want to continue) {
        throw new Error('Error in API 3');
      }
    })
  );
}
```

You can look at [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-vyf8ut?file=index.ts) for an examp.le

Comment: Thanks. I was able to run this fine, however I am not able to understand how can I catch response of api3() using Tap and apply some conditions to its response, and then based on that criteria decide whether to proceed to api4() or throw error and complete the process.

Comment: The example you showed checks for the country that is passed in argument, so i tried with `tap((resp) => {if resp.data === criteria})` to see if it fulfils criteria, but its only returning observable.

Comment: @Dhruvify can you explain in more details under which circumstances you want to stop the validations?

Comment: sure, so for an instance during the sequential api calls if somehow we can get hold of the response for `this.service.api2(id, name)` and if the response returns any wrong type of data e.g. if `resp.data !== validCriteria` we would like to halt our execution and avoid calling `this.service.api3(id, country),` and the rest of APIs mentioned in concatmap. Instead we just throw the error out and cancel the rest of the process. Can this be done?

Comment: Also by cancelling the rest of the process I mean that the process only needs to be cancelled for that particular object in an array for which api2 resulted validation failure, whereas, the validations can continue for other individual objects in parallel like what you shown above.

Comment: @Dhruvify with the implementation I suggest, in case of validation criteria of the api chain are not met, you block the processing of just ONE object. Consider that, when you call the `validate` function you get ONE observable that represents the validation chain for ONE specific object. If any of the api calls `throw` an exception, it cancels the execution of the api call chain for just that ONE objective.

Comment: yes, you are right. I just now tested it. Only one last question from my side, so currently in order to check the response for one particular api I have to wait until all responses are gathered in `subscribe()` block and then filter those responses. Is there a way to easily know what is the response when sequential calls are made e.g. inside api 3 can we do this `return this.invokeApi3(id, country).pipe( tap((resp) => { if (// check response first that can be matched with any criteria) { console.log('api3 response', resp) }})`

Comment: @Dhruvify I confess I do not understand your last question. Can you explain in more details what you want to achieve?

Comment: Yes, I mean in the answer above if we are executing api1, api2 and api3 sequentially, then is there a way to somehow check on the go (e.g. like without specifically subscribing) to know what is the response of lets's say api2 and then decide whether to execute api3 or throw error and exit for that object?

Comment: You can place any logic you want inside the function passed to the `tap` operator. So, as you are already suggesting, you can log on the console. A different situation is if you want to perform an async operation. In this last case you have to use again `concatMap` and place it between the calls to the apis.

Comment: okay got it, thank you very much! I have already started using your solution.

Comment: I was just playing around this some more and had a query that how can I stop this entire execution in midway (finishing api call chain also for all other pending objects) if using tap I satisfy certain condition for any object in lets say api2? just for my knowledge I am asking.

Comment: You can define a Subject, let's call it `stopAll` and then add in the `pipe` a `takeUntil(stopAll)` step. If you do so the pipe will complete its execution as soon as `stoppAll` notifies. Where to put `takeUntil` depends on the specific behavior you want to achieve.

Comment: Okay, I just tried adding it below mergeMap `mergeMap((obj) => validate(obj.id, obj.name, obj.country))` and in the pipe of validate concat function but it doesn't work, maybe because it runs in parallel for all objects and, I am passing true to stopAll after I subscribe to the response of api2 so that we break the entire chain if api2 doesnt offer me response I want. I will keep on trying.

Comment: If you can make a stackblitz example of what you want to achieve we can talk about it

Answer (score 2):

Switch map your data array into a stream of parallel pipes that join together.

```js
const dataArray: myData[];

of(dataArray).pipe(
  // switch and listen to the returned pipe
  switchMap(arrayOfObjects => {
    // a normal map (not an RxJS map), returns an array of pipes
    const nParallelPipes = arrayOfObjects.map(data => {
      const test1 = this.service.api_1(data.id);
      const test2 = this.service.api_2(data.id, data.name);
      const test3 = this.service.api_3(data.id, data.country);
      const test4 = this.service.api_4(data.id, data.name, data.country);
      return concat(test1, test2, test3, test4).pipe(
        catchError(error => this.handleError(error))
      )
    });
    // listen to all pipes in parallel, and only return when all pipes have completed
    return forkJoin(nParallelPipes) // or combineLatest(nParallelPipes).pipe(take(1))
  })
).subscribe(
  success => {
    console.log("validation succeed", success);
  },
  errorData => {
    console.log("validation failure: ", errorData);
  }
);
```

`nParallelPipes` contains n synchronous sequential validation pipes, where n is the amount of data in your initial array. ForkJoining them together (or combineLatest) will fire them off in parallel.

I hope that helps.

Happy coding.

---

> Is it possible to apply certain conditional checks on the response of API before moving to the next?

Yes. It is possible.

```js
const dataArray: string[];
const checkTest1 = (value) => true;
const checkTest2 = (value) => true;
const checkTest3 = (value) => true;
const checkTest4 = (value) => true;

of(dataArray).pipe(
  // switch and listen to the returned pipe
  switchMap(arrayOfObjects => {
    // a normal map (not an RxJS map), returns an array of pipes
    const nParallelPipes = (arrayOfObjects as string[]).map(data => {
      const test1 = this.service.api_1(data.id);
      const test2 = this.service.api_2(data.id, data.name);
      const test3 = this.service.api_3(data.id, data.country);
      const test4 = this.service.api_4(data.id, data.name, data.country);
      const startTesting = concatMap(value => iif(() => checkTest1(value), test1Passed, throwError('T1 Failed')))
      const test1Passed = test2.pipe(concatMap(value => iif(() => checkTest2(value), test2Passed, throwError('T2 Failed'))));
      const test2Passed = test3.pipe(concatMap(value => iif(() => checkTest3(value), test3Passed, throwError('T3 Failed'))));
      const test3Passed = test4.pipe(concatMap(value => iif(() => checkTest4(value), of('success'), throwError('T4 Failed'))))
      return test1.pipe(startTesting);
    });
    // listen to all pipes in parallel, and only return when all pipes have completed
    return forkJoin(nParallelPipes) // or combineLatest(parallelCalls).pipe(take(1))
  })
).subscribe(
  success => {
    console.log("validation succeed", success);
  },
  errorData => {
    console.log("validation failure: ", errorData);
  }
);
```

Comment: This is just what I want. Thanks. It runs really well but I just have few questions - 

Is it possible to apply certain conditional checks on the response of API before moving to next, e.g. before we move to API-2 we first apply some checks on API-1 resp and only proceed if it satisfies the criteria. is it possible?

Comment: second question, upon success I get to see list of all the observables like this `[0: Observable {source: Observable, operator: ƒ}, 1: 0: Observable {source: Observable, operator: ƒ}]` Can I use pipe to simplify them and know their contents?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `forkJoin` operator to call multiple endpoints in case you're only interested in the final response of all the endpoints and no more future emissions, it takes an array of observables and gives tou an array of responses then completes...something like this:

```js
const obs1$ = this.service.api1;
const obs2$ = this.service.api2;
const subscription = forkJoin([obs1$,obs2$].subscribe(([response1, response2]) => console.log(response1, response2))
```

but in case you'll be expecting more emissions from one or more observables you can use `combineLatest` or preferably `zip` operator.

Comment: Hi, in your case we are calling APIs in parallel using forkJoin but in my case it can be only called in sequence like Api-1, then API-2 and so on. 

The only parallel operation I want to achieve is as per my question, that based on array of objects how to call set of 4 sequential APIs in parallel for each object so we don't have to wait for so long until the last object inside array.